Document aggregation in MongoDB counting every hour
I have a collection in MongoDB with the following structure:
_id: 62ea5a456ca87a36b8dfc187
captureTime: 1659525000
country: "xxx"
deviceId: 158
picture: "c4ad8015-220d-4798-8626-05efcbee303b/202208031210002660.jpg"
plateNumber: "xxxxx"
sentido: 1

The collection has more than 26 million documents and I want to agreggation them to reduce the number of documents. The idea is to group by the diviceId field and count how many documents there are every hour. The resulting documents must have the value of diviceId, captureTime and the count.
I made the following aggregation in MongoDB Compass:
[
  {
    $project: {
      deviceId: 1,
      captureTime: {
        $toDate: {
          $multiply: ["$captureTime", 1000]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
$group: {
  _id: {
    deviceId: "$deviceId",
    hour: {
      $dateToString: {
        format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00Z",
        date: "$captureTime"
      }
    }
  },
  count: {
    $sum: 1
  }
}
  },
  {
$project: {
  _id: 0,
  hour: "$_id.hour",
  deviceId: "$_id.deviceId",
  count: 1
}
  },
  {
$sort: {
  hour: 1
  }
 }
]

The resulting document has the following structure:
count:19
hour: "2022-02-04T11:00:00Z"
deviceId: 120

The problem is that if I sum the count values ​​the result should be at least close to 26 million, which is the number of documents in the original collection. But the sum only gives me a value of 100,000.
Thanks in advance.

The pipeline seems ok to me. You could be running on some testing/experiment dataset instead of the "real" one since the 100k count looks too "neat" to me. Can you ensure you are running on the correct collection?

I'm sure it's the right collection. The very exact value of 100,000 in the sum also seems strange to me. I made the check because the document count after the pipeline is 2674 and it seems like a very drastic reduction to me.

I have found the solution in this link
Here it says that:

the aggregation pipeline builder is primarily designed for building pipelines, rather than executing them. That is, the pipeline builder allows you to easily plan and design your aggregation, and once you finished designing them, you should be exporting. The pipeline builder in Compass has which defaults to 100,000 documents

So, I copied the aggregation pipeline and ran it in mongosh and got the expected results.
